# How to remove route with IP?

Tags: linux, route, flooding

Used to ban some flood-bots with

```
route add -host $ip reject
```

But couple of 'good' IPs were banned as well.
My question is stupid (but I've searched and found no good solution (all were large and/or didn't work)):

How to unban it if I know the IP ?

Tried to use this:

```
route del -host 111.11.11.11
```

111.11.11.11 - just for example. I tried the exactly banned IP.

It said:

```
SIOCDELRT: No such process
```

Hoping for answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`route add 111.11.11.11 reject` blocks the IP.

`route del 111.11.11.11 reject` unblocks it.

Comment: Solved. Grand Merci!

Answer (score 3):

Use `man route`:

```
route del -host $ip
```

To block certain IPs you should however use `iptables` (`route` is not for firewalling).

```
iptables -I INPUT -s $ip/32 -j DROP
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I already tried route del, but it doesn't do the trick:  

s090:/home/www/web5 # route del -host [some ip]
SIOCDELRT: No such process